# what does while(pointer) and if(pointer) mean?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I don't know why 'currentNode'pointer is in () beside 'while' and 'if'.

```
Node* currentNode = head;
  while (currentNode) {
     Node* toBeDeleted = currentNode;
     currentNode = currentNode->next;
     delete toBeDeleted;
     ......}
```

---

```
Node* successor = currentNode->next;
  Node* predecessor = currentNode->previous;
  
  if (successor) {
     successor->previous = predecessor;
     ....}
```

Comment: Testing to see if it is nullptr. nullptr value is false, any other is true.

Comment: It's the same condition as `currentNode != nullptr`

Comment: Those are answers.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

A pointer variable is compatible with boolean in C. C considers every not-null pointer variable as `True`, and every variable pointing to NULL is considered as `False`.

Comment: "*A pointer variable is compatible with boolean*" - no, it is not. But, it IS *implicitly convertible* to a boolean. There is a difference.

Comment: It's also inaccurate to talk about _pointing to_ NULL. The conversion from a pointer type to boolean is based on the actual value of the pointer, _not_ what it points to. (For that matter, `nullptr` doesn't point to anything.)